# Android studio - link external library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, import

I'm having issues with linking the library to Android studio the correct way. I created external library and tried to link it to my project. What I actually did (not intended) was importing library but rather as a clone.
As a final result now there is duplicated source for my lib, one in actual library, one in project as imported module. Can I somehow link the library, so there is no actual source but a reference/link to it?

Screenshot of how lib is added to project:

[image: Adding a screenshot of how lib is added to project]

P.S: I used Project -> New-> Import Module with import option (first try I didn't have the import checkbox filled and the library was just empty)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for cloning the actual library or downloading it by yourself, you just need to import the library in the `build.gradle` file in your Android project like so:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.your.library:version.code"
    ...
}
```